# Size of custom checkbox drawable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I create a custom checkbox drawable:

```
<selector  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_checked="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_unchecked" />
    <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_checked" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_checkbox_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

Which I use like this:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
    />
```

I created two drawable images (one for unchecked and one for checked), one for each size (`xxxhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, etc).

However, my checkbox comes out like this:

[image]

Why does it come out so big? How can I make it smaller to 20x20dp?

Comment: fix the height and width of your checkbox.

Comment: Give the code ic_checkbox_unchecked.

Comment: @Uit14bs `ic_checkbox_unchecked` and `ic_checkbox_checked` are images.

Comment: you are using ic_checkbox_unchecked whats its size.

Comment: you are using wrap_content size in check box might be your drawable size is big that's why show the big checkbox

Comment: @ShubhankGupta I created a drawable for each size (`xxxhdpi`, `xxhdpi`, etc). How big should the checkbox be?

Comment: You can make the size of your image 20x20. By image i mean the png you are setting. and use wrap_content .

Comment: 1. change ic_checkbox_unchecked.png's size to 40*40 in xxhdpi and 60*60 for xxxhdpi.2.setButton in code.

Comment: @user5495265 I think you make your image `ic_checkbox_unchecked` by using xml

Comment: @user5495265 I am giving an example how to create this kind of checkbox using xml in answer Check this,

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `wrapcontent` try

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="20dp"
android:layout_height="20dp"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
/>
```

**Or**

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:button="@drawable/checkbox"
android:scaleX="0.40"
android:scaleY="0.40"
/>
```

Change the scale values until you achieve your desired `size`.

Comment: The checkbox becomes cut off (only a vertical line now): http://i.imgur.com/rqR70nf.png

Comment: @user5495265 Or try to scale it,check the edit again

Comment: @user5495265 I hope everything is now OK.

Comment: That doesn't give me 20x20dp though.

Comment: @user5495265 That was just an example,try to decrease the scale values to get your desired size

Answer (score 0):

You can create this kind of checkbox by using xml and you get the result what you want.

Make another layout file name as  `ic_checkbox_unchecked` and set this file as drawable insted of image.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
android:topRightRadius="0dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
/>
<solid
android:color="#FFFFFC"
/>

<size
android:width="25dp"
android:height="25dp"
/>
<stroke
android:width="3dp"
android:color="#236C87"
/>
```

You can chage width and height of by using `<size />` tag.
Also you can change border width by using `<stroke />` tag.